# TinyMCE Editor dosen't have all the features

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, tinymce

I used `TinyMCE` Editor for my text box in my web site, I followed this https://www.tinymce.com/docs/get-started/first-steps/  and it works fine but the problem is that I don't have all the features. mine is like the image below 
[image]

but here is what I Expect

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the full features (except premium plugins) you can use: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/full-featured/. You may want to modify `menubar`, `plugins` and `toolbar` for your need.

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',
  height: 500,
  theme: 'modern',
  plugins: [
    'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
    'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen',
    'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality',
    'emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools codesample toc'
  ],
  toolbar1: 'undo redo | insert | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
  toolbar2: 'print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons | codesample',
  image_advtab: true,
  templates: [
    { title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1' },
    { title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2' }
  ],
  content_css: [
    '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i',
    '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
  ]
 });
```